# How to Prevent FreeSWITCH from Adding Reason Header to SIP BYE and CANCEL?

Tags: voip, sip, freeswitch

I noticed that freeswitch adds a Reason header automatically to SIP BYE and CANCEL requests. I've successfully used the disable_q850_reason parameter to prevent FreeSWITCH from adding Reason headers to 3xx, 4xx, 5xx, and 6xx responses. Is there a similar parameter or configuration method to stop FreeSWITCH from adding the Reason header to BYE and CANCEL requests?
thank you!